# How to tell if your Android app has been approved by Google and can be rolled out on Google Play for initial public launch

Tags: android, google-play-console

We need to release our app on a specific date. I'm worried that after I publish the app, it might take several days to get through review process.

- I have turned on managed publishing on. (But haven't seen any option to set a date)
- The app status is "Closed Testing"
- The update status is blank.

When I create a new production release and choose one of the bundles that I have used for an internal test, I am able to review the release and see the "Start Rollout to production" button. Does that mean if I press that button, it will go live and be able to be downloaded pretty much straight away? Or will it then go to be reviewed and potentially take a week or more to get through review? I don't want to accidentally release it early but I also don't want to ruin the app launch by having the app in review on the launch date.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question after reading above comment link because it's related to specific app stores which could change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *Managed Publishing* turned **on**, clicking *Start Rollout to production* will **not** release the app right away.

[image: Play Console screenshot]

When app review is completed, you'll be able to release it from the *Publishing overview* tab:

[image: Play Console screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I've clicked rollout and it's now in review. I'll award bounty once I can. I might wait until I see the whole process through. Many thanks.